# Component gets data from its parent or directly from Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have the following component:

```js
const CompA = () => {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user);
  // ... the rest

  return (
    <div>
      <CompB />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This component uses the `user` data from `Redux` store. And I also have the `CompB` component that is a child of the `CompA` component, this component uses the `user` data from `Redux` store, too. There are two ways for the `CompB` to get the data:

- Gets the data from its parent through `props` or `context`.
- Gets the data directly from the `Redux` store by using `useSelector` hook (like its parent).

I'm struggling to choose one from those approaches. Which one is better and why? Thank you.

Comment: Those are nested and context would be great in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `<CompB />` is a dump component and he shouldn't know anything about enviroment and business logic the best option would be to do it with `props`. Otherwise, use `useSelector` in `<CompB />`.